# Drag and drop like dropbox to import

Tags: django, csv, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have csv files that i want to import to django models.
I want a feature whereby i can drag and drop the csv file and it automatically imports this csv to a django models(like we do in dropbox).
Anyone with an insight on this please.
An example will be much appreciated.
Regards,
Josh

Comment: Brandon,I have no idea,so i just want an insight on this before i try anything

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish what you're asking. There is native drag-and-drop support in HTML5, jQueryUI, vanilla JavaScript, etc. All possibilities involve JavaScript and kicking off a process on the backend to iterate over the csv file via Ajax.

Comment: Great thanks..can you please give me a link to one such native drag and drop support?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/